# Researching references for common Ubuntu problems

Tags: discussion

Many problems on this website create the appearance that something is missing from Ubuntu and that a remedy might involve `sudo apt install`. Unfortunately many posted solutions do not have references. For example is the following.

askubuntu has a web page for the following problem.

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

The answer with the most up-votes has 389 up-votes. [askubuntu.com link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342202/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-but-already-installed)

The solution with the most up-votes does not seek to install using the same string that is cited in the error message. In other words the answer is not `sudo apt install canberra-gtk-module`. The solution with the most up-votes is somewhat similar to that but not exactly. Since it is not exactly that, ideally the correct answer or the most up-voted answer should have a reference to a canonical source.

How can I independently verify via referencing canonical sources that the most up-voted answer is the correct answer?

Comment: I don't think there are "canonical sources" to reference on this. The commands are different because some prefer `apt` while others prefer `apt-get`. Welcome to the maze of linux uniformity. As time progressed, and gtk3 became prevalent, `canberra-gtk3-module`  became available, whereas `canberra-gtk-module` is gtk2.

Comment: @mikewhatever That some people use `apt-get` is not the only difference.

Comment: The shift from `apt-get` to `apt` was introduced in Ubuntu 16.04. https://itsfoss.com/apt-vs-apt-get-difference/

Comment: @wyphan I have not encountered advice that `apt-get` is still useful for the vast majority of users so I always use `apt` now.

Comment: There was `apt-get` when I started with Ubuntu, and apt was added later. There was no shift, as `apt-get` is still as useful as before, so why change.

Comment: If an answer would be improved with a reference link, feel free to propose an edit, or write a new up-to-date answer, or leave a comment suggesting specific improvements. If an answer has, over time, become misleading or counterproductive but remains highly voted, please flag it..

Comment: For example, I answered a popular question back in 2012, about Ubuntu 11.10. Does this answer still apply to Ubuntu 20.10? Is it my responsibility to check? Every release?

Comment: @mikewhatever The most upvoted answer at the link uses `apt` and I also use `apt` so the difference does not arise from the installation program. This question is about the package names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For packages, you can always verify with a search on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/).